# Problems calling instance method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Following code changes tab name and select then index 2.

```
[(UITabBarItem*)[self.rootController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"User"];

self.rootController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

However, it works for example when app didFinishLaunching method but not working when called like follows.

touch up inside button triggers renameTabs:

```
- (IBAction) renameTabs: (id)sender
{
    CompanyAppDelegate *theInstance = [[CompanyAppDelegate alloc] init];
    [theInstance rename];

}
```

and in the controller:

```
- (void) rename
    {

        [(UITabBarItem*)[self.rootController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"User"];

        self.rootController.selectedIndex = 2;

    }
```

rename function is triggered and also defined at .h. No errors but nothing changes! Is there anything wrong?? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't create new `CompanyAppDelegate`. Try to implement method `sharedAppDelegate` in `CompanyAppDelegate.m`:

```
+ (CompanyAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (CompanyAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

Don't forget to declare it in `CompanyAppDelegate.h`.

And replace `renameTabs` with this one:

```
- (IBAction) renameTabs: (id)sender
{
    CompanyAppDelegate *theInstance = [CompanyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
    [theInstance rename];
}
```

Comment: Hi, still crashing. Now rename is not reached, receive a Sigabrt signal when trying to call rename.

Comment: Is your `CompanyAppDelegate` looks like this: `@interface CompanyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>`? What returns `[CompanyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];`?

Comment: yes, looks like @interface CompanyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> and [CompanyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]; returns 0x5b59350 and (gbd) on output terminal.

Comment: solved, bad declaration of rename. Your solution works great! sorry for insistance. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction) renameTabs: (id)sender
{
    CompanyAppDelegate *theInstance = (CompanyAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [theInstance rename];

}

- (void) rename
    {

        [(UITabBarItem*)[self.rootController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"User"];

        self.rootController.selectedIndex = 2;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ah, when I first read this I thought you said rename wasn't reached.  Never mind.]

Comment: Yes, rename is reached and executed with no errors but seems that doing anything